# Evaluating the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- e^x} \ln (x)\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I  got stuck on evaluating the following integral. I do not know how to evaluate it . Could you please help me, thanks in advance: $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- e^x} \ln (x)\, \mathrm dx$

Comment: Is it solvable?

Comment: Otherwise you could use numerical integration

Comment: What is the context of this integral?

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives an approximation of $-0.276339.$

Comment: I guess this is just the famous Euler integral, but with $e^{-e^x}$ instead of $e^{-x}$. The original integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \ln x dx=-\gamma$

Comment: Mathematica gives for the moments of the double exponential: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-e^x} x^n dx = n! G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,\ldots,1 \\
 0,\ldots,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ which is (a) way too complicated (contains Meijer-G function) and (b) doesn't even help in your case, since the logarithm can't be expanded around $0$